# ContentPage with updatePanel using jQUERY in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I need to change my contentPage to another without any change in MasterPage using updatePanel and JQuery.Can anyone suggest?Am new to Ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking to load in the html from another page? Or does the content page which you are wanting to load in have postbacks and dynamic controls on it?

If it is just simple html, then look at the [jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) method

```
$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```